# Highlighting specific rows in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

Hi I'm still learning how to use visual studio and the format editor and need some assistance. I have to make a new summary report and be able to highlight certain needs above a certain percentage such as >15% or <15%. I have to use a math formula to determine if it's over the 15%.

```
1-({@dspStkWip}+{tblItem.OnOrderQuantity}/{@dspNeed}
```

To show that the total is 15% or greater we're using red.

```
if 1-({@dspStkWip}+{tblItem.OnOrderQuantity}/{@dspNeed}) >= .15 
    Then crRed
       else crNoColor;
```

We have part numbers on the summary so those cannot be highlighted when we export to excel. so it doesn't interfere when we copy the part number to our own programs. I don't know if I have to add new parameters or fields to this showing that it's above the percentage. 
If any one can help that would be really amazing.
If anyone needs more info on this I will gladly show.
I'm also using VS2005.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Rows of what?  `ListView`?  `DataGridView`?  Something else?  You mention exporting to Excel.  Do you mean rows in Excel?  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: So what we do is take the summary report and export is to excel to show from highest need to our stockwip. to show us what we need to prioritize buying. Instead of using formulas after formating the right way on excel we're just making a new report right on VS.

Comment: So I have to highlight the highest need to buy that we don't have for the stockwip. the whole row which I can give the rest of the fields if necessary. Sorry I'm still new to visual studio but I'm learning it fast as I can. So 1 row say is 15% and we need to buy it needs to be highlighted but, the part number cannot be highlighted because it will not paste into our own program we made here.

Comment: Also I have a picture of what I mean but I have no idea how to show on site without a link.

Comment: Row of what? You say "report" but many people use that term generically and thus meaninglessly.  If you mean an actual report, like using Reporting Services or Crystal Reports, then you need to say that. If you just mean a form with some controls on it then you need to explain EXACTLY what controls you're using because what you need to do depends completely on the specifics of the situation. I can't tell you how to colour a row because you haven't told us what a row is. Conceptually we all know what a row is but that concept can be realised in innumerable ways.

Comment: I apologize, we use crystal reports.

Comment: I have added the CR tag to your question, although you might want to replace that with a more specific version tag.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I still have no idea what I'm doing with this report. Let me know If I can help in anyway explaining because I know I'm bad at it and I apologize